# What are the current differences between tuxonice and µswsusp?

Tags: linux, kernel, hibernate

I tried to find out what is the current comparation between TOI and µswsusp. Unfortunately I could not find any recent information about the state of hibernation in Linux and how TOI compares to µswsusp (the most recent information I found is from 2009 in [talk of merge](http://lwn.net/Articles/333007/) between Nigel, Machek and Wysocki).

The [features matrix](http://tuxonice.net/features) seems to be partially out-of-date as [µswsusp](http://suspend.sourceforge.net/) supports "Multithreaded I/O" since 1.0. Does anyone know some more up-to-date comparison?